# Recursive notations with forall quantifier

Tags: coq, notation

How can I implement a notation of the form: `∀ x ≤ y ≤ .. ≤ z ≤ t, φ` in Coq?

A similar notation (but without quantifiers) appears [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#notations-with-recursive-patterns)

```
Notation "x ≤ y  ≤ ..  ≤ z ≤ t" :=
    ((fun b A a => a <= b /\ A b) y 
 .. ((fun b A a => a <= b /\ A b) z (fun b => b <= t)) 
 .. x)
  (at level 70, y at next level, z at next level, t at next level).
```

But I was unsuccessful in putting forall quantifiers to it.

Comment: IIUC forall quantifiers in notations don't work very well anyway. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200157/implicit-arguments-in-a-computed-type-in-coq

Answer (score 2):

There is a `binder` keyword for binders in recursive notations.

```
Notation "'exists' x .. y , p" :=
  (ex (fun x => .. (ex (fun y => p)) ..))
  (at level 200, x binder, y binder, right associativity).
```

See the [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/master/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html?highlight=notation#recursivenotationswithbinders) for details.